# How to set option of selecting customer group on customer registration form

Tags: magento2

I want to give option to customers to select there customer group in magento 2 on customer registration page.

Comment: Hi All, I am also having same issue. Could some on please help us?

Answer (score 2):

Check in this class **Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection**
you will get one method **toOptionArray()**. so you can create object of this class and get all groups and group id in array. so you can add add this on your customer registration page as a dropdown. and you can save value of group same way like magento save value of other customer attribute.

Hope it helps. 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi , how we can make customer group multiselect on customer registration in registration form at backend Magento 2?  Thanks